# catching id passe in url using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have an html block like this:

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="content">
    <h3><a href="/dir/dir/dir/?id=33" title="name">name</a></h3>
    <a href="/dir/dir/dir/?id=33" title=""><img src="/default.png" alt="name" /></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to catch the `id` value (here 33) from the first `<a href>` tag.

My code is:

```
function getID(s){
    var s = $(this);
    var a = s.('a:first').attr('href').split('=');
    console.log a[1];
}
```

However console.log is returning me:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (

any idea?

Comment: `s.(` is invalid, and that is not printed by `console.log`. Your code is just not valid JavaScript, it is not executed because the parser cannot even parse it.

Comment: should you use console.log as a function? console.log(a[1]);

Comment: thanks felix, I deleted "." which gives me     var a = s('a:first').attr('href').split('=');
but does not return me any id...

Comment: @breteuil: It wouldn't because `s("a:first")` doesn't make much sense. It's the same as `$("a:first")`. How is your function `getID` called? What is `this` in it?

Answer (score 2):

Here’s a simple jQuery plugin:

```
$.fn.getID = function() {
  return this.prop('href').split('=')[1] || '';
};
```

Use it as follows:

```
$('a').first().getID(); // '33'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
function getID(){
    var theId = $('h3 a:first').attr('href').split('=')[1];
}
```

The ":first" is not mandatory as you only have one  element in your  element.